# Represent a positive integer as a product of its factors

Tags: output-formatting, factorization

I am trying to illustrate some simple ideas with exponents.   I can manually express something like $5^4$ as $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$, but wondered how to get *Mathematica* to do that for me.

I found the example below in the documentation, but can't figure out how to "massage" it to work with a number that only has one factor, for example I would like $625$ to be represented as $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$:

```
CenterDot @@ (Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[20!])
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: For several years now there has also been the [`InactiveFactorInteger`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/InactiveFactorInteger/) ResourceFunction, though it does not expand non-distinct factors like you want, e.g. `ResourceFunction["InactiveFactorInteger"][12]` returns $2^2\times3$ .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a way that seems to work:

```
CenterDot @@ Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[20!]]
```

[image]

```
CenterDot @@ Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[625]]
```

[image]

To get the number back, merely do

```
Times @@ expr
```

where `expr` is the name for the expression that results from the code above.

Answer (score 11):

You can also make use of `Inactive` to allow you to calculate the value later.

Starting with march's solution and altering the `Apply`.

```
n = 20!;
t = Inactive[Times] @@ Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n]]
(* 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*5*5*5*5*7*7*11*13*17*19 *)
```

`t` can be `Activate`d to calculate the value.

```
Activate@t == n
(* True *)
```

Hope this helps